# React Native using react-native-audio-toolkit how to access files

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, react-native-ios

So I can record something with the following code

```
let rec = new Recorder("filename.mp4").record();

// Stop recording after approximately 3 seconds
setTimeout(() => {
  rec.stop((err) => {
    // NOTE: In a real situation, handle possible errors here
    // Play the file after recording has stopped
    new Player("filename.mp4")
      .play()
      .on('ended', () => {
        // Enable button again after playback finishes
        this.setState({disabled: false});
      });
  });
}, 3000);
```

I can perfectly record audio but how I can access or delete or list recorded files like filename.mp4. Where is this saved in Android or iOS? Will these remain there after each update to app or each recompilation etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [react-native-audio-toolkit documentation](https://github.com/futurice/react-native-audio-toolkit/blob/master/docs/API.md#recorder-properties) you can get the file parth with `fsPath` property.

> **fsPath - String (read only)**
>
> Get the filesystem path of file being recorded to. Available after
>   prepare() call has invoked its callback successfully.